# Get Json Array in Post Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have a problem when I want to retrieve an array from a post response

this is my post

```
{
    "user_email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "user_password": "12345"
}
```

and this is my post response , I want get the token value

```
{
    "status": true,
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Request Succeded: Login success",
    "data": [
        {
            "token": "bsWIVXTLuud2ZbdnUvI8037fT7D0t7MTvusBrNjskah"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my model LoginModel.java

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data ;

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData (Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public LoginModel(String user_email, String user_password) {
    this.user_email = user_email;
    this.user_password = user_password;
}
```

Data.java

```
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
   this.token = token;
}
```

there code I'm tried before ,the text view show nothing

```
LoginModel loginModelresponse = response.body();

String token = loginModelresponse.getData().getToken();

textView.setText(token);
```

I want get the token from my post response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data value is an array of tokens, not an object itself

Create a Token class with a token String field, then replace the Data class like so

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Token> data ;
```

To get the token, you must iterate the list

Comment: how to iterate the list ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your LoginModel class, because your response data object is Array type

```
public class LoginModel {
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Data> data = null;

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Integer getCode() {
return code;
}

 public void setCode(Integer code) {
 this.code = code;
 }

 public String getMessage() {
return message;
 }

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public List<Data> getData() {
return data;
}

 public void setData(List<Data> data) {
 this.data = data;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) site to generate a correct response class in java

```
 public class Tokens implements Serializable
    {

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1577013820593763604L;

    public String getToken() {
    return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
    }

    }
  //  -----------------------------------com.example.Response.java-----------

    package com.example;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Response implements Serializable
    {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private boolean status;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private long code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Tokens> data = null;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -3002290394951662690L;

    public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
    }

    public long getCode() {
    return code;
    }

    public void setCode(long code) {
    this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
    return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Tokens> getData() {
    return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Tokens> data) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    }
```